# jQuery Sortable how to set all children as a drop target

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I found this greate plugin:
https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

I would like to have possibilty to drop daggable elements into every child. I've tried to do this adding an empty `<ol></ol>` but it dosnt work on run. I would have to do this before I build sortable tree. But I do everything dynamically.

And according to documentation:

> name: drop
>   default: true
>   description: If true, items can be droped onto this container

So I understand that it should work that way out of the box?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

The working solution:

```
$("ol.sortable").sortable({
  // animation on drop
  onDrop: function  (item, targetContainer, _super) {
    var clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({height: 0})
    item.before(clonedItem)
    clonedItem.animate({'height': item.height()})

    item.animate(clonedItem.position(), function  () {
      clonedItem.detach()
      _super(item)
    })
  }
})
```

I think that removing this fragment:

```
  group: 'simple_with_animation',
  pullPlaceholder: false,
```

from configuration helped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nested lists work only when the `li` elements have a nested container (an `ol` or an `ul`) at the time the plugin is initialised.

You mentioned that you construct your tree dynamically. So, every time you add a new `li` in your tree, you will need to execute the following line to make the new node nestable:

```
$li.removeData('subContainers');
```

Only make sure the `li` has an `ol` or an `ul`, i.e.:

```
<ol class="sortable">
    ...
    <li>
        Your New Node
        <ol></ol>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

---

Now, why exactly the line `$li.removeData('subContainers');` works?
Looking inside [the plugin code](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/blob/master/source/js/jquery-sortable.js) you might notice that when the plugin makes a decision whether to allow a drop inside a list item or not, it calls a method `hasChildGroup` ([see line 506](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/blob/master/source/js/jquery-sortable.js#L506)), which, in turn, calls another method `getContainerGroup` ([see line 572](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/blob/master/source/js/jquery-sortable.js#L572)), where it calculates and stores the information about the children, and possible drop targets of the node being hovered. The calculation happens only once and every subsequent drop attempt will reuse this data.

This is exactly what we should attack and erase this information from the node's `data` to make it re-calculate the data the next time.

[`'subContainers'` is the key that the plugin uses](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/blob/master/source/js/jquery-sortable.js#L159) to get the information and find a possible drop target. Therefore the entry with exactly this key should be removed from the node's `data`.

Comment: thanks for Your help and explanations. I think I've figure it out.